# Write a log file using Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, add-in

My objective is to write a log file, once a user open a PPT file and Travers to different slides, system write this information in log file.

Till now I tried following solutions:
1. Create a Add-in (PPA) and attach it manually in PPT file. 
2. Create a button on first slide and on click event call Auto-Open event.

But ultimately I want to implement a solution to install Add-in by making entry in REGISTRY.

I already read this great article http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00469_Add_-_install_an_addin_via_the_registry.htm

Comment: and what issue did you have when you followed the advice in the link?

Comment: I did make entry in Registry. basically the idea to do changes in registry was to have the addin available on the machine irrespective of the user logged in, I had done changes in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.  used below code:     RegistryKey registryKey64 = RegistryKey
    .OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);                                                               registryKey64.SetValue("Auto_Event","Path of PPA file");

Comment: OK I'll guess the issue: The add in is not available for all users? Is the add in available for any users?

Comment: According to this, HKLM doesn't work: http://skp.mvps.org/ppafaq.htm#17 I guess it's a security issue. According to this you _can_ if you use the Office 365 Admin centre: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Deploy-Office-add-ins-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f

Comment: HKLM does work. I've installed add-ins this way for years. IT departments may lock down HKLM so individual users can't access it, though. And I don't understand what CurrentVersion\Run and AutoEvent=path to ppa file have to do with the registry settings suggested in the PPTFAQ article.

Answer (score 0):

I work along with Abhishek on this. This addin is only available to the user logged in and loaded the addin via file->options->cutomize ribbon. But we want to make this addin machine specific so that we dont have to load the addin each time.

Thanks and Regards,
RS

Comment: This is just addon information to the question. Not an answer.